# Construct a topological manifold which its open cover is locally finite but not globally

Tags: general-topology, locally-compact-groups, smooth-manifolds

The whole question is like this:

1-4. Let M be a topological manifold, and let U be an open cover of M .

(a) Assuming that each set in U intersects only finitely many others, show
that U is locally finite.

(b) Give an example to show that the converse to (a) may be false.

(c) Now assume that the sets in U are pre compact in M; and prove the con-
verse: if U is locally finite, then each set in U intersects only finitely many others.

I'm still tackling the part b).

From John Lee, "Smooth manifold" Problem 1-4

Comment: Hint: Take one of your open sets equal M.

Comment: I have answered this question somewhere else:
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/649352/topological-manifolds-covers/871707#871707