# Topological Manifolds & Covers

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

This problem is from John Lee's "Introduction to Smooth Manifolds"

1-4. Let M be a topological manifold, and let U be an open cover of M .

(a) Assuming that each set in U intersects only finitely many others, show that U is locally finite.

(b) Give an example to show that the converse to (a) may be false.

(c) Now assume that the sets in U are pre compact in M; and prove the con- verse: if U is locally finite, then each set in U intersects only finitely many others.

I think I have been able to successfully proof part a). I am stuck on part b) and c).

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: $U$ can be big enough to intersect a lot of open sets in the covering, however for being locally finite you just have to pick an open subset of $U$. However when you have compactness you have a finite subcovering

Answer (score 1):

I'm reading his introduction to topological manifolds :)! I'll solve (b) and (c) (since you have found (a) yourself):

(b) Let's look at the real line $\mathbb{R}$ and as a cover we take:
$$ \mathcal{U} = ]0,\infty[ \cup \{]-n-2,-n[ \cup ]n,n+1[ \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\}  $$
this is clearly an open cover of $\mathbb{R}$ and $]0,\infty[$ has a nonempty intersection with every element of $\mathcal{U}$ and clearly $\mathcal{U}$ is an infinite set. I think it is clear that this set is locally finite.

(c)  Assume \mathcal{U} satisfies the condition and let $U\in \mathcal{U}$. From John M. Lee's book "introduction to topological manifolds" we know that $\overline{\mathcal{U}}$ is also locally finite thus for each $p \in \overline{U}$ we find some neighbourhood $V_p$ s.t. $V_p$ only intersect a finite number of sets in $\mathcal{U}$ since $\overline{U}$ is compact we find a finite subcover $V_{p_1},\dots,V_{p_n}$, now we have that $\overline{U} \subseteq V_{p_1}\cup \dots \cup V_{p_n}$ and since each $V_{p_i}$ only intersects finitely many members of $\mathcal{U}$ this also holds for $\overline{U}$ thus also for $U$.